# Maven permission denied

Tags: maven, tomcat, war, exploded

I'm getting strange exception while trying to create exploded war directory with maven. And it's strange because I already changed all files permissions to 777 for everyone.
What should I check? Ican't find any useful info in stacktrace :(

Goals I execute:

```
install war:exploded tomcat:redeploy
```

Here's stacktrace:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:exploded (default-cli) on project app-web: Failed to copy file for artifact [com.kk:app-core2:jar:app-SNAPSHOT:compile]: D:\kk\app-2013\app-core2\target\classes (Odmowa dostępu) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:exploded (default-cli) on project app-web: Failed to copy file for artifact [com.kk:app-core2:jar:app-SNAPSHOT:compile]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to copy file for artifact [com.kk:app-core2:jar:app-SNAPSHOT:compile]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.ArtifactsPackagingTask.performPackaging(ArtifactsPackagingTask.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.WarProjectPackagingTask.handleArtifacts(WarProjectPackagingTask.java:195)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.WarProjectPackagingTask.performPackaging(WarProjectPackagingTask.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:479)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildExplodedWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:412)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarExplodedMojo.execute(WarExplodedMojo.java:43)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\kk\app-2013\app-core2\target\classes (Odmowa dostępu)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1067)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1049)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFile(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:304)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask$1.registered(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructure.registerFile(WebappStructure.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFile(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.ArtifactsPackagingTask.performPackaging(ArtifactsPackagingTask.java:112)
    ... 26 more
```

EDIT POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <parent>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.kk</groupId>
        <version>2013-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>app-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Application</name>
    <dependencies>
        <!- whole lot of dependecies->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/html</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeResources>true</excludeResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/IMediaManager.java</include>
                        <include>**/CachableMediaManager.java</include>
                        <include>**/BaseApplication.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.kk</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-cache</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>app-web</finalName>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.kk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>app-web-config</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <properties>
                <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: is file D:\kk\app-2013\app-core2\target\classes exists? the reason for asking error says: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\kk\app-2013\app-core2\target\classes

Comment: Yes, it exists, it's a directory and has full control permissions for everyone.

Comment: mmm and why it's not saying: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: "D:\kk\app-2013\app-core2\target\classes\NameOfTheFileToDeploy.extension" ?

Comment: Well, sorry, I just now noticed that part of stacktrace is translated :/
It should say:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\kk\app-2013\app-core2\target\classes (Permission denied)

Comment: Why does this a folder having permissions for everyone ? A build will use that locally so only permissions for the user who is running the build are needed. Can you show the pom file? Furthermore this looks like a windows machine and you are telling about 0777 permissions which are unix sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: I added POM to my post :)
It has permissions for everyone because I had no idea who's permissions maven uses by default for building process

Also sorry for that 777, it's a Win7 machine, I just use Linux a lot and that was a mental shortcut.

Comment: As you say @k_k, 'Permission denied' is the point for your issue. Check this directory and user accessing